# Glitch in HTML Color Visualizer

Tags: javascript, html

I have a color visualizer on my website in which visitors can design metal buildings. You can view it [here](https://www.metaldepotinc.com/BuildingDesignerRayburn.html). Now, when you are on the visualizer clicking through the colors, notice how the building colors change for the wall, roof, and trim colors. However, when clicking through the "Door Color" swatches, the door colors will not change. I've inspected my code and still can not find where this issue is coming from. I'm seeking another pair of eyes that could possibly help me fix this issue. Thank you in advance.

```html
<html>
  <body>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        window.print();
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
<br>
<html>
  <style>
    .mySlides {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
    }

    .active {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var slideIndex = 1;

    function plusDivs(n) {
      showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentDiv(n) {
      showDivs(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
      if (n > x.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
      }
      if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = x.length
      }
      var children = x[slideIndex - 1].parentElement.getElementsByTagName('img')
      var clickedElement = x[slideIndex - 1]
      for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i] != clickedElement) {
          children[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
      }
      clickedElement.classList.toggle("active");
    }
  </script>

  <body>

    <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px;position: relative;">
      <div class="wall-colors">
        <img src="http://metaldepotinc.com/XBackground.png" style="width:100%;position: absolute ;z-index:-1">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWA.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWAG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWBR.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWBS.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWBS2.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWBW.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWCB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWCG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWCG2.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWCR.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWDS.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWFG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWHB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWHB2.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWKB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWLS.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWMB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWPW.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWRR.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWSG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWST.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWSW.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWSW2.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="roof-colors">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRA.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRAG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRBR.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRBS.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRBS2.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRBW.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRCB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRCG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRCG2.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRCR.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRDS.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRFG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRHB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRHB2.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRKB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRLS.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRMB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRPW.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRRR.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRSG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRST.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRSW.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XRSW2.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="trim-colors">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTA.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTAG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTBR.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTBS.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTBS2.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTBW.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTCB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTCG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTCG2.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTCR.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTDS.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTFG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTHB1.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTHB2.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTKB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTLS.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTMB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTPW.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTRR.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTSG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTST.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTSW.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XTSW2.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="door-colors">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XDPW.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XDGW.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XDRR.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XDFG.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XDHB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XDLS.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XDBS.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XDST.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XDSG2.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XDKB.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XDCR.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="wainscot-colors">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWS1.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWS2.png" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="XWS3.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="as-console-wrapper">
      <div class="as-console"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>    
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p><font face="arial black">WALL COLOR</font></p>

    <img onclick="currentDiv(1)" src="BA300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(2)" src="BAG.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(3)" src="BB.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(4)" src="BBR300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(5)" src="BBS.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(6)" src="BBS2300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(7)" src="BBW300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(8)" src="BCB.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(9)" src="BCG1.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(10)" src="BCG2300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(11)" src="BCR.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(12)" src="BDS.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(13)" src="BFG.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(14)" src="BG.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(15)" src="BHB1.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(16)" src="BHB2300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(17)" src="BKB.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(18)" src="BLS.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(19)" src="BMB300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(20)" src="BPW.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(21)" src="BRR.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(22)" src="BSG300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(23)" src="BST.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(24)" src="BSW.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(25)" src="BSW2300.png" />

    <BR>
    <br> <p><font face="arial black">ROOF COLOR</font></p>

    <img onclick="currentDiv(26)" src="BA300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(27)" src="BAG.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(28)" src="BB.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(29)" src="BBR300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(30)" src="BBS.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(31)" src="BBS2300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(32)" src="BBW300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(33)" src="BCB.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(34)" src="BCG1.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(35)" src="BCG2300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(36)" src="BCR.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(37)" src="BDS.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(38)" src="BFG.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(39)" src="BG.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(40)" src="BHB1.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(41)" src="BHB2300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(42)" src="BKB.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(43)" src="BLS.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(44)" src="BMB300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(45)" src="BPW.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(46)" src="BRR.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(47)" src="BSG300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(48)" src="BST.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(49)" src="BSW.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(50)" src="BSW2300.png" />
    <BR>
    <br> <p><font face="arial black">TRIM COLOR</font></p>

    <img onclick="currentDiv(51)" src="BA300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(52)" src="BAG.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(53)" src="BB.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(54)" src="BBR300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(55)" src="BBS.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(56)" src="BBS2300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(57)" src="BBW300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(58)" src="BCB.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(59)" src="BCG1.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(60)" src="BCG2300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(61)" src="BCR.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(62)" src="BDS.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(63)" src="BFG.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(64)" src="BG.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(65)" src="BHB1.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(66)" src="BHB2300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(67)" src="BKB.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(68)" src="BLS.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(69)" src="BMB300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(70)" src="BPW.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(71)" src="BRR.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(72)" src="BSG300.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(73)" src="BST.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(74)" src="BSW.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(75)" src="BSW2300.png" />
    <BR>
    <br> <p><font face="arial black">DOOR COLOR</font></p>

    <img onclick="currentDiv(76)" src="BPW.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(77)" src="BGW.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(78)" src="BRR.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(79)" src="BFG.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(80)" src="BHB1.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(81)" src="BLS.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(82)" src="BBS.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(83)" src="BST.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(84)" src="BSG2.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(85)" src="BKB.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(86)" src="BCR.png" />
    <br>
    <br> <p><font face="arial black">WAINSCOT COLOR</font></p>

    <img onclick="currentDiv(87)" src="BWS1.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(88)" src="BWS2.png" />
    <img onclick="currentDiv(89)" src="BWS3.png" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <center>
      <p><font face="arial">*SIGNATURE 300 PANELS COST 35% MORE THAN SIGNATURE 200 PANELS.</font></p>
      <br>
      <p><font face="arial">SOME COLORS ON SCREEN MAY VARY FROM ACTUAL RESULTS. </font></p>
    </center>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just tested and some door colors do work. Other don't. The same seems to apply to all colors though. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, I see where three door colors work.

Comment: Open your browser's console and look at the errors. You're getting 404s on some images. JS seems to be fine (but your HTML is antiquated). Avoid inline JavaScript, the `<font>`, and `<center>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your image source, you dont seem to have a https://www.metaldepotinc.com/xDFG.png file for example